# Sql - inner join tables having single column

Tags: inner-join

I have 2 tables, Table A has one column with values 1,1,1,2,2,3 and Table B has a column with values 1,2,3. What is the output for `inner join` for table A and Table B with explanation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a blatant homework dump

Comment: As an attempt to give some advice before your question gets closed - have you tried to do the operations in your question? It's pretty basic SQL which should be too search results of you search for Inner joins.

Comment: See sqlfiddle.com. Read & act on [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also: (Obviously:) This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @PM77-1 You don't need to assume anything about the asker, just inform them. And downvote, close vote, etc. "Blatant" is a presumption.

Answer (score 0):

An `INNER JOIN` will match the values of the indicated columns and only return the rows for which a match was found.

In the above example, the resulting table would contain the values 1,1,1,2,2,3 - this is because the `INNER JOIN` will have found a match for each value of the Table A.

Comment: Please do not answer such duplicate or non-reasearched questions, downvote & flag/vote as too broad, duplicate etc. See my comment on the question.